# didRangeBeaconsInRegion delegate keep on calling iBeacon iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

i am using this tutorial [iBeacons](http://www.devfright.com/ibeacons-tutorial-ios-7-clbeaconregion-clbeacon/#more-517) run this code in iPad4 device as the beacon and iphone5 as the receiver. I notice two things with the SDK

1) Even though i am in the same position, delegate method(didRaneBeaconsInRegion) is getting called frequently with different distances. Basically its not getting stable even though the user is in the same position.

2) When i move with the device, the distance between the beacon and the receiver is showing a wrong values often.I need to know whether can i rely on the distance or completely on the proximity?

I'll really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are talking about instability in the "accuracy" field.  Despite its name, this is an *estimate* of the distance between the iBeacon and the device in meters.

As you have seen, there is a lot of noise on this reading.  This is because it is based on the measured Bluetooth signal strength (rssi), which is inherently unstable.   As Timo's response says.  Apple's class reference for CLBeacon recommends against relying on this field  as an absolute distance measurement.

The "proximity" field doesn't tell you anything that the accuracy field doesn't.  It just puts the accuracy value into one of four buckets (immediate, near, far, unknown), so it doesn't change quite as much.  But at times you still see it change back and forth between two adjacent proximity values.

Answer (score 1):

> proximity: The value in this property gives a general sense of the relative distance to the beacon. Use it to quickly identify beacons that are nearer to the user rather than farther away.
>
> accuracy: Indicates the one sigma horizontal accuracy in meters. Use this property to differentiate between beacons with the same proximity value. Do not use it to identify a precise location for the beacon. Accuracy values may fluctuate due to RF interference.

Comment: Please add reference to where you take the quote from.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions :

1) The beacon range is a purely based on RSSI values observed from the beacon. The distance as seen by the accuracy attribute is the perceived distance and not the actual distance. This has a lot of dependancy on the strength of the broadcasting radio. The easiest way to maintain a stable range is - sliding average / moving average (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) of RSSI values at each didRangeBeaconsInRegion call.
Another good way of doing it is as described in caliberation process from Apple's Airlocate sample :

```
// Measured power is an average of the mid-80th percentile of RSSI samples.
                        NSUInteger outlierPadding = allBeacons.count * 0.1f;                    
                        [allBeacons sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"rssi" ascending:YES]]];
                        NSArray *sample = [allBeacons subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(outlierPadding, allBeacons.count - (outlierPadding * 2))];
                        measuredPower = [[sample valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.rssi"] integerValue];
```

2) When i move with the device, the distance between the beacon and the receiver is showing a wrong values often.I need to know whether can i rely on the distance or completely on the proximity?
Again , you cannot rely on any of this. The accuracy is observed distance and proximity is determined from measuredPower attribute which is nothing but a average RSSI from 1m distance.